# How make group of the JSON data of same key

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am working in php.I have the JSON data in which muliple data comes some data have two same keys as shown below

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "imgId": "1",
            "gallery_name": "Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc": "Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status": "1",
            "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a31fb4ca9.jpg",
            "image_tittle": "2.jpg",
            "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "imgId": "3",
            "gallery_name": "Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc": "Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status": "1",
            "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a469c88aa.jpg",
            "image_tittle": "Gallery-img-1-updated here",
            "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
        }
    ]
}
```

How show JSON data like

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "imgId": "1",
            "gallery_name": "Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc": "Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status": "1",
            "items": [     
                {  
                    "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a31fb4ca9.jpg",
                    "image_tittle": "2.jpg",
                    "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a469c88aa.jpg",
                    "image_tittle": "Gallery-img-1-updated here",
                    "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My means make an array of same key values. By a little search i found that this may possible with the foreach loop but how implement with multiple keys dont know.
I tried with the code. But dont get the optimal solution

```
$items=json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($items as  $item) {
foreach ($item as $key => $value)
{
   if( is_array($value) ) { 

      foreach ($value as $subkey => $part)
      {
          foreach ($part as $partkey => $partvalue)
          {
              echo $key .' '. $subkey . ' ['.$partkey.'] => '.$partvalue."\n";
          }
      }
   } else {

    echo $key.' => '.$value."\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: You should really try to solve the issue yourself first. Show us that you made an effort and tried something. We'll be glad to help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't wright it for you. SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Then show us your attempts. While you're at it, lease read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Update you question with any additional code/info. It's unreadable when posted in comments.

Comment: Please Explain the down vote. It may help me for the future when i try to ask a new question

Comment: I didn't see the timing of the downvote on the question, but it may have been because you didn't include your coding attempt when you first posted your question.  Now that you have included your coding attempt as an edit, you can delete your comment with the code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4b5f0ef48310336a3f725aea358358cff0d3b82))

```
$json='{
    "statusCode": 800,
    "status": "Sucess",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "imgId": "1",
            "gallery_name": "Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc": "Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status": "1",
            "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a31fb4ca9.jpg",
            "image_tittle": "2.jpg",
            "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "imgId": "3",
            "gallery_name": "Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc": "Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status": "1",
            "image_name": "sdna_gallery_img_5662a469c88aa.jpg",
            "image_tittle": "Gallery-img-1-updated here",
            "image_url": "assets/uploads/school/410920433/gallery/10803076"
        }
    ]
}';

$array=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array['result'] as $a){
    if(!isset($result[$a['id']])){
        $result[$a['id']]=array_slice($a,0,5);  // only retain the first subarray's first 5 identifying elements
    }
    $result[$a['id']]['items'][]=array_slice($a,5); // push last 3 elements from each subarray
}
$result=array_slice($array,0,2)+["result"=>array_values($result)];  // re-index subarrays, and prepend the first two elements
var_export(json_encode($result));
```

Output:

```
'{
    "statusCode":800,
    "status":"Sucess",
    "result":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "imgId":"1",
            "gallery_name":"Schools DNA Gallery",
            "gallery_desc":"Gallery desc for Demo public senior secondary school-1 Status : published",
            "gallery_status":"1",
            "items":[
                {
                    "image_name":"sdna_gallery_img_5662a31fb4ca9.jpg",
                    "image_tittle":"2.jpg",
                    "image_url":"assets\\/uploads\\/school\\/410920433\\/gallery\\/10803076"
                },
                {
                    "image_name":"sdna_gallery_img_5662a469c88aa.jpg",
                    "image_tittle":"Gallery-img-1-updated here",
                    "image_url":"assets\\/uploads\\/school\\/410920433\\/gallery\\/10803076"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```